# Setup a proxy server using Windows Authentication (NTLM)?

Tags: proxy, windows-authentication, ntlm

I want to setup a proxy server using Windows authentication (formally NTLM), I know that there are better protocols that could be use (Digest, etc.). I've been struggling to find information on how to set it up.

So far I figured out that you need to get an IIS server and setup proxy forwarding on it. Sadly nothing is working yet, any information that you might have would be greatly appreciated.

**An ideal answer** would be a step by step guide on how to setup a windows authenticated proxy server.

Comment: What are you looking to accomplish with a proxy server? IIS isn't considered a proxy like [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/). If you'd like IIS to be the front-end of high availability, then there are different design considerations.

Comment: It's for testing some software that i would like to be able to authenticate using NTLM